# Python - My tkinter button always looked pushed

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

Very dumb question but in my Python 2.7 program (which works perfectly) the buttons of my tkinter GUI always take their graphical pushed position whenever I click on them. Is this a known issue, and is there any way around this?

Comment: Perhaps you could improve your question by providing a short executable example of code that exhibits your problem.

Comment: Are you using a basic tkinter button or a ttk button? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Not a known issue. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: It would be almost impossible to give you an answer without  testable  code. There are so many different variables when dealing with bugs it could be literally anything. Please provide a reproducible snipit of code.